# Find only exact word maches using SphinxQL

Tags: sphinx

I'm trying to use Sphinx to find rows having `words` in their `title` column.

The query looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MATCH ('@title "words"')`

But it also returns rows having `word` (without the `s`) instead of `words` in the title.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have `morphology` (specifically stemming?) enabled on the index.

Should consider enabling `index_exact_words`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-index-exact-words

which gives you exact form operator.

```
MATCH('@title =words')
```

Also gives you the possibility of the interesting `expand_keywords` option :)
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-expand-keywords

... or if dont *ever* want these matches, could disable stemming :) Alas there isn't a 'stemming optional' mode. (eg a ~ fuzzy operator to specifically stem)